# How to reference implicitly typed model in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm learning MVC and I'm trying to create an implicitly typed variable for my model but not sure how to reference it in the view `@model IEnumerable<???>`

Controller...

```
public ActionResult Users() {
    var model = from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()
                select new {user = u, roles = string.Join(", ", Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName))};

    View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an anonymous type you're returning. I believe you'll want to use an actual type. If you don't have one for what you're selecting in your query, you'll want to create one.

Once you have your type, here's an example of using it in the view.

This is the first line in my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<AutoTrackerCommon.Entities.TrackerJob>
```

And I'm using it in a WebGrid:

```
@{
    var grid = new @WebGrid(
        source: Model,
        rowsPerPage: 10);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't reference an anonymous-typed variable in the view (or anywhere outside its local scope).  It's possible to use a *dynamic* type:

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
```

But this way you don't have Intellisense/compile-time type checking; the best approach would be to just create a class for your model.

Answer (score 1):

You reference it as `Model`, but why would you do such a thing? 
Use ViewModels, don't go with untyped or implicitly typed models. Its a nightmare to work with: you lose everything from IDE support to automatic validation. Don't complicate your life unnecessarily. View Models (or strongly typed views) are the way to go.

Good article to read about this: [View Models in ASP.NET MVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

Hope this is of help to you & good luck